# Linux on USB 3.0 flash drive/SSD disc - load to RAM or standard boot

Tags: linux, liveusb

I am thinking of getting myself a portable (generic x86_64) Linux distro (Gentoo or Kali) on a USB stick. The thing is that I am unsure whether to:

1. load it to ram at boot (as some livecds do), or
2. treat it as a normal sys and just boot it.

What I am most concerned with is speed. Which one of the two would be faster? Do you have any personal experience or any benchmarks at your disposal for the task in hand?

Also, should I go for the option #1:

- Is this approach even suited for running say awesomewm/unity, basic dev tools, ...
- Is there a way of rewriting the image (permanently, not just in ram) whilst the system is running (sw update, ...)? If so, can the image be split into multiple parts so that I don't have to overwrite the entire image?